# Integrals with azimuthal symmetry

Tags: electrostatics, dipole-moment, multipole-expansion

The dipole moment is given by

$$\textbf{p}=\iiint \textbf{r'}\rho(\textbf{r'}) \;\mathrm{dV}$$

let's say that the charge configuration is a sphere with radius R and that the charge density is $\rho$ in the northern hemisphere and $-\rho$ at southern hemisphere. But when i calculate the dipole moment in sphercial coordinates

$$\textbf{p}=\iiint \limits_{\mbox{northern hemisphere}} \textbf{r'}\rho_0 \;\mathrm{dV} -\iiint \limits_{\mbox{southern hemisphere}} \textbf{r'}\rho_0 \;\mathrm{dV}=$$ 
$$\widehat{r}2\pi R^4/4\int \limits_{\mbox{northern hemisphere}}sin\theta \;\mathrm{dV} - \int \limits_{\mbox{southern hemisphere}}sin\theta \;\mathrm{dV} $$

which is zero.

I understand that the dipole moment should point in the **z** direction and replacing **r** with **z** yelds correct answer. My question are:
1. why do i get wrong answer when i use the definition of the dipole moment?
2. how would i solve for the dipole moment in this case if i didn't know where it pointed?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the calculation you carried? How did you proceed with the integrals?

Comment: i used spherical coordinates and the calculations are sraightforward

Comment: I guessed that is the case. Nevertheless, something is probably wrong with what you're doing if your dipole vanishes, so showing what you've done in the question text might be at help.

Comment: Evidently they're not straightforward, because you dropped a sign somewhere! If you show more steps, we can help identify the mistake.

Comment: The integrals are integrated seperately, the r integral gives R^4 /4 and the phi integral gives 2pi while the theta integral gives 0 so the integral is zero

Comment: @hola You can't just take $\hat{r}$ outside the integral since it is a function of the angles.

Comment: You asked the same question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/369290/126734

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the integrals wrong. Notice that $\vec{r}=(r\sin\theta\cos\varphi,r\sin\theta\sin\varphi,r\cos\theta)$ and you need to evaluate for example

$$\rho_{0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{R}\vec{r}r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\varphi$$

for the northern hemisphere. Can you manage from here?

Comment: why do i need to rewrite the vector r?

Comment: I'm not rewriting it, I'm just substituting it explicitly. This vector depends on the angles and you ignore that when you take $\hat{r}$ outside the integral.

Comment: thats where i went wrong. that whas what i was looking for thank you!

Comment: Also can you answer me this: how do i figure out where the dipole moment points in general, for example in this case, how can you see that the dipole moment points in the z direction?

Comment: Just calculate the integral and it will show up. The result of this integral is a vector, you don't need to choose the direction *a priori*.

Comment: i know that, but it would simplify my calculations if i beforehand knew the direction of the dipole moment

Comment: You can use symmetry considerations. For example in this case, assume that your dipole vector has a component not in the $\hat{z}$ direction. Now rotate the sphere around the $\hat{z}$ axis. The charge distribution remains the same, and the dipole vector is not. This is a contradiction. The only way to overcome this is to assume the dipole points along the $\hat{z}$ axis.

Answer (score 0):

I might understand how you got 0 as a result, but it's not the correct answer. The two hemispheres aren't equal, so their difference isn't 0.

Let's take a sphere of radius $R$, with the charge distribution described in the question. Then the integrals become:
$$\int \limits_0^R \mbox{d}r \int \limits_0^{\pi/2} \mbox{d}\vartheta \int \limits_0^{2 \pi} \mbox{d}\varphi\, \begin{pmatrix} r \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\varphi) \\ r \sin(\vartheta) \sin(\varphi) \\ r \cos(\vartheta) \end{pmatrix} \rho_0\, r^2\, \sin(\vartheta) - \\ \int \limits_0^R \mbox{d}r \int \limits_{\pi/2}^\pi \mbox{d}\vartheta \int \limits_0^{2 \pi} \mbox{d}\varphi\, \begin{pmatrix} r \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\varphi) \\ r \sin(\vartheta) \sin(\varphi) \\ r \cos(\vartheta) \end{pmatrix} \rho_0\, r^2\, \sin(\vartheta) =$$
$$= \rho_0 \int \limits_0^R r^3\ \mbox{d}r \int \limits_0^{2 \pi} \left( \int \limits_0^{\pi/2}  -  \int \limits_{\pi/2}^\pi \right) \begin{pmatrix} \sin^2(\vartheta) \cos(\varphi) \\ \sin^2(\vartheta) \sin(\varphi) \\ \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\vartheta) \end{pmatrix} \mbox{d}\vartheta\, \mbox{d}\varphi =$$
$$= \rho_0 \frac{R^4}{4} \left[ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \left. (\vartheta - \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\vartheta)) \right\vert_0^{\pi/2}\, \left. \sin(\varphi) \right\vert_0^{2\pi} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \left. (\vartheta - \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\vartheta)) \right\vert_0^{\pi/2}\, \left. \cos(\varphi) \right\vert_0^{2\pi} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \left. \cos^2(\vartheta) \right\vert_0^{\pi/2}\ 2\pi \end{pmatrix} - \\ \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \left. (\vartheta - \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\vartheta)) \right\vert_{\pi/2}^\pi\, \left. \sin(\varphi) \right\vert_0^{2\pi} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \left. (\vartheta - \sin(\vartheta) \cos(\vartheta)) \right\vert_{\pi/2}^\pi\, \left. \cos(\varphi) \right\vert_0^{2\pi} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \left. \cos^2(\vartheta) \right\vert_{\pi/2}^\pi\ 2\pi \end{pmatrix}\right] =$$
$$= \rho_0 \frac{R^4}{4} \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} = \frac{\rho_0\, R^4}{4} \vec{e}_z$$